# Nginx basic auth and number of authenticated locations

Tags: authentication, nginx

Im using basic auth in nginx, no issue there, but i would like to limit the number of distinct locations a user is authenticated,
The end goal is to prevent user sharing access data to website, since the website does real time "monitoring" of some data, i wan't that if the same user/pass combination is used from another ip, that or either both users stop getting data,
or one of them stops getting data.

Comment: How does "monitoring" occur? Is it a permanent connection kept open via nginx? What's the desired behaviour when the same user/pass is used, will http 403 do? Can a user have multiple sessions from the same ip in parallel?

Comment: one session per ip

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a good idea, because a user may log in via pc and mobile phone at the same time and has two different ip addresses that way. Also http-auth isn't designed to do what you want it to. It would have to remember the ip-address and make it expire somehow, when the user leaves without logging out. Altogether would it be difficult to guess for how long the session is valid. Another problem is, that most users don't have static IPs and get disconnected by their providers every 24 hours. What happens if that occurs after a valid login?

The most popular method to deal with this kind of problems are session-cookies. These can be described as a one time password and you can use that for as long as you want or until it expires. SessionIDs are usually saved in some kind of database and making those sessions unique would not be a big deal and may therefor be what you want. Luckily the 
[ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) would allow you to only implement this missing part and would bring you as close as you can get without developing your own nginx-module (see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/ for available modules).

On the other hand: Don't do that. Seriously. If you care for security, do not try to reinvent the wheel and use something, that has already proven. E.g. [ngx_http_auth_jwt_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html) allows you the use of [OpenID](http://openid.net/), which also sets you free from saving sensible user data on your server (because nobody wants to save passwords unless it is absolutely necessary).

Both of these methods require nginx-modules, which may not be installed on your server. If you don't have the permissions to build them, I would suggest to add that to your question, so that others can suggest solutions for non root servers.

If you want to keep it simpler you should also consider to generate download links each and every time and save ip-address and download link address in a database. Delete entries when a user downloads that file and you are done. For that to work you can use the 
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME`-HTTP-Header, so that your `download.php` doesn't save a file that called alike.

May be you can also find some kind of javascript to replace `ngx_http_auth_jwt_module` and use OpenID with http-auth. That can work, because it is possible to do the authentication with ajax as well.

Last but not least: If you still want to do http-auth, also use HTTPS, because your passwords won't be encrypted by this auth-method by default.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is unusual so you will need to write a lot of the logic to handle the process.

Your code will need to store a User ID and IP Address pair for each loged in user and validate each attempted log in against this. As the previous answer pointed out, you will need to expire logins etc. Basically, you need to roll a session handler.

This is not impossible or particularly difficult but you need to write it yourself in one of the scripting languages available to Nginx which are either Perl, which is not recommended due to limited ecosystem in Nginx, or Lua, which is highly recommended due to the massive Nginx lua ecosystem (used by Cloudflare for instance).

You will need to compile in the [3rd party Nginx Lua Module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and associated modules or just uninstall Nginx and use the [Openresty Bundle](https://github.com/openresty/openresty) which already has everything you will need included instead ... including Redis for storage if you need to scale up.

Here are some tools you can use as your building blocks

[Openresty Session Library](https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-session)

[Openresty Redis Session Library](https://github.com/brg-liuwei/lua-resty-redis-session)

[Openresty Encrypted Session Module](https://github.com/openresty/encrypted-session-nginx-module)

Note that you can implement Openresty stuff directly in Nginx if you wish without having to run Openresty as it is just a convenient bundle of Nginx and useful module.